# Create constant for dynamic controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an application where the controls on the form will be created at run-time using web-service. Web-Service return a class object using that information I create control on the UI.

The problem that I am facing is when the controls are rendered on the UI and I want access any one of the control I need to specify name which is hard-coded , as below.

```
TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)Controls["txtbx1"];
```

Since the names of the control are also dynamic I don't want to hard-code them.

What is the best solution to solve this problem

Comment: well, I hope you create the UI from a model using perhaps `DataTemplate`, or alternatively, xaml serialization. Secondly, why do you want to access `TextBox`? Unless you're not following MVVM, the need to access `TextBox` is very slim.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [FindName(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the containing FrameworkElement (e.g. Window or other container control): `TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)mainWindow.FindName("txtbx1");`